# How can I Wrap an Apex:image with a condition inside a pageBlockTable Column?

Tags: pageblocktable, images, pageblock, conditional

I want to display different images inside this `pageBlockTable` `Column` based on the value of a field. 
I am receiving this error:

> You may specify either a ''value'' attribute or a body for the column
>   component, but not both

Here is the code:

```
<apex:pageBlock rendered="{!showPI}">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listPICompleted}" var="item">
          <apex:column footerClass="itemHeader" value="{!item.Item__c}"/>
          <apex:column footerClass="subAreaHeader" value="{!item.Sub_Area__c}"/>
          <apex:column footerClass="actionStatementHeader" value="{!item.Action_Statement__c}"/>
          <apex:column footerClass="reviewStatusHeader" value="{!item.Plan_Review_Status__c}">
                   <apex:image value ="{!IF(item.Plan_Review_Status=="Not Submitted", URLFOR($Resource.NotStarted),
                        IF(item.Plan_Review_Status=="Re-submit"), URLFOR($Resource.NotStarted),
                        IF(item.Plan_Review_Status=="Approved"), URLFOR($Resource.Complete),
                        IF(item.Plan_Review_Status=="Received"), URLFOR($Resource.Pending),
                        IF(item.Plan_Review_Status=="Submitted"), URLFOR($Resource.Pending) )}" width="20" height="20"/>
           </apex:column></apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Does anyone know what the proper way to do this is? should I  not be using a pageBLockTable? alternatvely to this, I also tried using the IF Condition in a style tag to change the background as opposed to an apex:image tag, however salesforce does not recognize the closing tag for the column when i do this.

Your help is very much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specify both the value attribute AND include a body for the `apex:column`

Easy fix though just change it to:

```
<apex:column footerClass="reviewStatusHeader" >
                   <apex:image value ="{!IF(item.Plan_Review_Status=="Not Submitted", URLFOR($Resource.NotStarted),
                        IF(item.Plan_Review_Status=="Re-submit"), URLFOR($Resource.NotStarted),
                        IF(item.Plan_Review_Status=="Approved"), URLFOR($Resource.Complete),
                        IF(item.Plan_Review_Status=="Received"), URLFOR($Resource.Pending),
                        IF(item.Plan_Review_Status=="Submitted"), URLFOR($Resource.Pending) )}" width="20" height="20"/>
           </apex:column>
```

If you need the text for plan review status simple add an output field before the `apex:image`

Comment: Hi thank you very much this worked,  unfortunately though doing this keeps the table header's title for plan review status blank. Do you know how I can keep the field name inside the header while still generating images as opposed to the text?

Comment: AH HA! I found it, i had to use apex:facet name= header